# Check random number generated does not already exist; cannot convert array to object

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I've searched around and haven't found any solutions that apply to google script api.

BACKGROUND: trying to populate a 1 row x 4 column array with (1) a random six-digit number, that does not already exist in column 1 (2) today's date (3) user-inputted store number (4) user-inputted number of boxes.

In this script, we first open a dialogue box that requests the user input the store number, and the number of boxes. This (and other) information will be populated at the last row.

I have two issues here.

ISSUE #1:
I do not know of a way to check the random number generated against what already exists in column A. I need to be able to create a unique random number.

ISSUE #2:
Upon running the script with a placeholder for the random number, I receive an error that "Cannot convert array to object[][]" -- I'm not sure where I am going wrong here.

```
function onOpen() {
SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Create New Exception Number')
  .addItem('Add New Exception Number', 'showPrompt')
  .addToUi();
}

function showPrompt() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 

  var storeNumPrompt = ui.prompt(          //receive input for Column C data
  'Please enter the store number.',
  ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  var numBoxesPrompt = ui.prompt(          //receive input for Column D data
  'Please enter the number of boxes.', 
  ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*999999); //random number for Column A, that does not already exist in Column A
  var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "PST", "dd/MM/yyyy"); //Today's date to go in Column B
  var storeNum = storeNumPrompt.getResponseText(); //value based on user input
  var numBoxes = numBoxesPrompt.getResponseText(); //value based on user input
  var lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Exception Numbers').getLastRow()+1; //determine what is the last row
  var values = [randomNum,today,storeNum,numBoxes];

  var newException = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Exception Numbers').getRange(lastRow,1,1,4); //gets the range of the last row, 4 columns wide
  newException.setRange(values); //sets the values as previously specified in the last row.
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did mean setValues!!! Thank you for that. I still receive the same error.
I am unsure of what in this script is causing the Object[][] error.

Comment: I changed newException.setRange(values); to newException.setValue(values) and this populates all 4 columns with randomNum. When I try newException.setValues(values), I receive the same error as stated in the question

Comment: I have corrected the object[][] error by changing setRange(values) to setRange([values]). Thank you for your help thus far. Do you have any recommendations for ensuring that the random number generated does not already exist in Column A?

Comment: Make sure your question is accurate regarding the code you are using, and the specific question you are attempting to solve. Why do you need this specific kind of random number? it is not random if there are required to be no duplicates. What happens if you have 1m rows? Your script will run forever, as it cannot create a number that does not exist in that range.

Answer (score 0):

Create a large set of 'random' numbers, remove duplicates from the set and each time you need another pick the next.